# Apache Camel Code Generation in JBoss

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

What API and which function (please mention function name and github.com repository if available) is called on camel JBoss Developer Studio IDE when we drag and drop components to palette i.e., Code generation from Design to Source editor?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JBoss Fuse Tooling for Eclipse](https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! After looking at the git repo,I realized they are using java to do this.Which technology does JBoss use to perform this conversion between Design and Source?Are they using any external API?

Comment: They use Eclipse Modeling Framework (https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) and Graphiti (https://eclipse.org/graphiti/)

Comment: We don't use EMF really. We are using a POJO model for Graphiti which is our own. We basically read the XML into that POJO model and then fill the Graphiti diagram with that pojo model. Switching between Source and Design view is just converting the pojo model to XML and vice versa. Btw. we have a channel on FreeNode IRC #fusetools. You can join that one and ask us there too ;)

Comment: [lhein](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3844627/lhein) i just based my answer on looking through manifest files and finding there emf packages as required. See [here](https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide/blob/3de67e50e3eedeb9a0f1c87d88266fe423557560/editor/plugins/org.fusesource.ide.project/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L35) and [here](https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide/blob/7d2463e88d42ebe1cccbd9837d89c9b1e628e11a/core/tests/org.fusesource.ide.camel.tests.util/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L20), for example

Answer (score 2):

the diagram is based on [Eclipse graphiti](https://eclipse.org/graphiti/). [EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) is not used, we are using our own internal java model.

The repository is effectively this one: https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide
The Drag'n'drop is mainly implemented in classes of this package: https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide/tree/master/editor/plugins/org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor/src/org/fusesource/ide/camel/editor/features

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to contribute, we can guide you directly on the github project or on our JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/projects/FUSETOOLS/

Regards,